# Using Interlocks for thread synchronization and maintaining cache coherency

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, synchronization, interlocked

If I were to use some kind of algorithm that uses InterlockCompareExchange operations on a variable in C++ that determines if a set of data is being written to by a particular thread (by creating my own little lock), how do I ensure that the interlocked operation that updated the value is immediately seen by the other thread if the data is being stored in say, level 2 cache on an i7.

I know that cache coherency is used to keep the data across caches of multi-core processors consistent, but what about the small frame of time when one core updates a variable with an interlock function and the cache checks and fixes coherency problems all while another core is checking that variable it has in its own cache?  Would this problem be fixed if I ensured the variable that is having the InterlockCompareExchange operation is volatile so that changes are written directly to the memory?  Am I correct to believe that a memory barrier (MemoryBarrier() on VS) does not ensure cache coherency but only ensures unwanted instruction reordering?

I hope my question isn't too vague.  I will try to answer any comments if I was.  I don't have any source code to post with this question as I don't have any specific problems, but would like to know for future reference if there could be any problems with this, especially with c++0x having interlocks as part of its standard library.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no "immediately". Everything written will be seen by the other cores eventually. The absolute time when something will be seen is nothing to worry about, only the order relative to other writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't reorder loads or stores across an interlocked function call, and the implementation will include whatever machine instructions are needed to make sure the CPU core won't.

Cache coherency is always maintained, the only thing you have to worry about is when the value actually gets written out from the instruction pipeline to cache, and that's an ordering issue.

Comment: So when one thread on one core performs an Interlocked operation on a variable, then new value that is written to the cache and the cache coherency immediately tells the other caches that their cache line with that value is not longer valid without waiting even a few clock cycles?  Also, would it be faster to use a volatile anyways so the cache lines don't need to be flushed in case there are other values in the cache line that need to be used as well?

Comment: @JAKE: on many architectures, all cache <-> memory transfers take place a line at a time, even if not all values were modified